# How to check if a varaible is an interface or an array of the interface in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have tried to find many solutions on the internet and have found none. This is a simplified version of what I'm trying to acheive:

```
interface list {
    people: Person | Array<Person>
}

interface officialList {
    people: Array<Person>
}

toOfficialList(list: List): officialList {
    //I need a way of figuring out if list.people is just one person or array of people
    //Returns official list, turning "Person" into "[Person]"
}
```

If a list with an array of people is used, then the function doesn't need to do anything and can just return the same thing back.

If a list with just one person is used, then the function should convert that into an array with one person in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that a `Person` is not itself an array, you can use [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) to distinguish between a `Person` and an `Array<Person>`.  I'd write your `toOfficialList()` implementation like this:

```
function toOfficialList(list: List): OfficialList {
  return { people: Array.isArray(list.people) ? list.people : [list.people] };
}
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4CwAUMsiHALYQBcyGYUoA5gNzEC+xxoksiKAGWD18xUgAcIWcQBsaaTDmQAfZAEEoUOAE8APOijYQAPg5ciPaPCTIA8jBjAEwODKEjCJZJOlzaGrT0DI1MiTiJiGABXEAQwYCUwLHtHZ1d3MAAKGWEwWgyASloUpxc3XNEvKAgwKKhcPG8pWXkAnQA6YTbtbNz2nxaC5AB+ZBz6fua5ZFoAbXGwSd8IAF1kdjYw8yA)

Comment: Thank you, this method worked, and the editor that I used (Visual Studio Community 2019) Detected the if / else and didn't show an error.